# How to listen mouse click in background in android

Tags: java, android

I am creating an android application and want to show Toast on mouse right click and left click.
The default listner is

```
public boolean onGenericMotionEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if(event.getActionButton() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Left click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

It runs perfectly when my app is opened. How can I do it in background (say while using WhattsApp)?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: How do you even have a mouse on an Android device? Are you using some kind of custom driver and hardware to plug in a mouse to an Android device? Also, your code is basically performing an action (showing a Toast message) when your remove your finger from the screen.

Comment: I am using OTG converter to use mouse with my phone

Comment: when I click the left button on my mouse then the toast shows

Comment: @Shankha057 Support for mouses has been there for quite sometime.. heard of tablets that has external keyboards and bt connectivity to mouses?

Comment: @aksappy nope, never heard of any. I thought that the point of touch screen devices where Android is used are meant to be touch based and wondered why would you need a mouse when you could touch.

Comment: Check this project out - https://github.com/chetbox/android-mouse-cursor .. I am not the author, but this might give you some ideas

Answer (score -1):

When your app is in the background, the way to make it work is by using a [`Service`](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services#java). Start the service when your app is `onPause` (on `onStop` for API level above 23). And in the `onStart`, check if your `Service` is running and [stop it](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-check-if-a-service-is-running-on-android).
If you are using `Fragment` then adapt this according to the `Fragment`'s lifecycle.